# webpack npm run start command gives error

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I want to split my project into modules with webpack, but when I want to run my webpack server, I get an error, how can I solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqWZv.png)

How can I solve the problem I mentioned?